# vue js push parameter to URL

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am using vuejs 3 and I want to filter the products. In the first stage I want to send parameters to URL and I am using vue router for this.
Currently, my filter only send one params to URL from each group but I want to append all params to url from first group and from second group I want to push only one params to URL(either medium or large)

my filter is like this `localhost:8080/filter?color=red&size=medium` when I select red color and medium size.
But if I select two colours, it should append both colours and my URL should be as below `localhost:8080/filter?color=red&color=blue&size=medium` or `localhost:8080/filter?color=red&color=blue&size=large`

```
  <template>
            <div class="products">
                <div class="multi_filters">
                    <h1>Multi Filter By Color</h1>
                    <a href="#" @click.prevent="activateFilter('color','red')">Red color</a>
                    <a href="#"  @click.prevent="activateFilter('color','blue')">Blue color</a>
                </div>
    
                <div class="single_filter">
                    <h1>Multi Size</h1>
                    <a href="#" @click.prevent="activateFilter('size','medium')">Medium</a>
                    <a href="#"  @click.prevent="activateFilter('size','large')">Large</a>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </template>
       <script>
                export default {
                    data() {
                        return {
                            filters:{},
                            selectedFilters:{}
                        }
                    },
                    methods:{
                        activateFilter(key,value){
                            this.selectedFilters = Object.assign({},this.selectedFilters,{[key]:value})
                            console.log(this.selectedFilters)
                            this.$router.replace({
                                query: {
                                    ...this.selectedFilters
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create data for this app like this , `urlParams` to get everytime someone click on color or size and push to it.

```
data() {
    return {
      colors: [{id:1, name: "red" }, {id:2, name: "blue" }],
      sizes: [{id:1, name: "medium" }, {id:2, name: "large" }],
      urlParams: []
    };
  },
```

And some method:

```
methods: {
    activateFilter(e) {
      //get color or size with condition not exist.
      if(!this.urlParams.includes(e)){
        this.urlParams.push(e);
      }

      //create params url
      const urlParam = this.urlParams.reduce((contains, current) => {
        if(this.createArrName(this.colors).indexOf(current) > -1){
          return contains += `color=${current}&`
        }else{
          return contains += `size=${current}&`
        }
      }, '')

      //adapt to url
    },
    createArrName(arrs) {
      return arrs.reduce((contains, current) => {
        return contains.concat(current.name)
      }, []) 
    }
  },
```

And template you write loops of colors and sizes:

```
<template>
  <div class="products">
    <div class="multi_filters">
      <h1>Multi Filter By Color</h1>      
      <a v-for="item in colors" :key="item.id" @click.prevent="activateFilter(item.name)">
        {{ item.name }}
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="single_filter">
      <h1>Multi Size</h1>
      <a v-for="item in colors" :key="item.id" @click.prevent="activateFilter(item.name)">
        {{ item.sizes }}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks for help. When I clicked the color on page, it throws error in console tag. error is`Uncaught TypeError: this.urlParams.include is not a function
    at Proxy.activateFilter`

Comment: sorry it should be includes (not include). I'm typing code without test. Can you try again

Comment: thanks, but nothing happened when I clicked the color and size, no any error in console and params are not send to URL